# Get in tree line input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I get this in tree line input?

This is my input:

```
3
asd
aaa
```

The desired output: `2`

This is my code so far:

```
number = int(input("print a number: "))

thisList = []
thisList1 = []

for i in range(number):
    thisList.append(input("print main string base on number: "))
       
for i in range(number):
    thisList1.append(input("print equal string: "))
    
count = 0
for i in range (len(thisList)):
    if (thisList[i] != thisList1[i]):
        count = count + 1
print (count)
```

Comment: Hi mahdi, I am afraid you might have to elaborate further what you are trying to achieve. You want user to input a length of string and generate a string based on that?

Comment: mmm.. sorry.
what do you mean?

Comment: From your example, I can not understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain further?

Comment: in line one i input a number after in line tow input a string base on the number..
and line tree.. user should set string like line tow..

Comment: now the program check what difference between them and show the number of incorrect alphabet

Comment: was that clear?

Comment: i'v wrote this.. but is wrong.

thisList = [] thisList1 = [] 
number = int(input("print a number: "))
thisList.append(input("print main string base on number: "))
thisList1.append(input("print equal string: "))
count = 0
for i in range (len(thisList)):
    if (thisList[i] == thisList1[i]):
        print (0)
    else:
        count = count + 1
    print (count)

Comment: Could you please explain your goal with natural words... What are we doing? :)

Comment: If i'm not mistaking: the first input is a number (the number of words the user will give as an input). Then the user inputs some words. Now you want to check how many words arent the same?

Comment: @kabooya
yap .. right

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are the same size, you can run a for loop with the index of one of the strings and check them like this

```py
s = "aaa"
s1 = "aab"
counter = 0
for x in range(len(s)):
    if not s[x] == s1[x]:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Again what are you expecting from this script? To compare two strings? What's an equal string... with same characters and same length but with different order ?

Comment: To compare two strings

Comment: @mahdi It isn't wrong, you just haven't really described the question sufficiently. Please describe the input, the input type, and the expected result/expected result type.

Comment: I want to have three input lines in this program.
The first line of a number
The second line is a string of letters whose number is determined by the number of letters.
In the third line, I ask the user to enter the same letters.
In the output I want only one number that indicates the difference between the two strings of letters.
If the letters were entered in two identical lines, the number in the output is zero.
For example, if the number of letter differences is in two letters, the number in the output is doubled.

Comment: What do you do with the first line of a number? The lines posted above to follow the rest of the specifications. In your code above, you're inputting the strings as lists rather than strings.